# How can I access a nested JSON attribute in python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

How do I access the description field in my request payload?

REQUEST PAYLOAD:

```
data = { "other_details" :{
            "my_story":true,
            "preferences":false,
            "profile_photo":false,
             },
             "experience_detail":[
                        {
                        "description":"Location: Indan\nCurrent job 
                         responsibilities:\n\n• To manage, interpret, 
                         and integrate inspection and function test data associated 
                         with pressure relief 
                         devices\n• Collection and Managing the database of 
                         inspection/test records\n",
                        "employer_name":"Wood Group",
                        "end_date": "2020-04-28",
                         "id": "30dbe99d0c55435ea3d5119ece0ac873",
                         "is_current_employer": true,
                         "job_title": "Integrity Engineer",
                         "start_date": "2013-11-25"
        
                         },
                         {
                        "description":"Location: Indian\nCurrent job 
                             responsibilities:\n\n• To manage, interpret, 
                             and integrate inspection and function test data 
                             associated with pressure relief devices\n• 
                             Collection and Managing the database of 
                             inspection/test records\n",
                         "employer_name":"QUESS CORP.",
                         "end_date": "2020-04-28",
                         "id": "30dbe99d0c55435ea3d5119ece0ac873",
                         "is_current_employer": true,
                         "job_title": "Integrity Engineer",
                         "start_date": "2013-11-25"
                         }
             ]
       }
```

I tried a few ways, but they didn't work.

Attempt 1:

```
def index():
    data = json.loads(request.data)
    clean_description = (data['other_details'] 
                             ['experience_detail']['description'])
```

Output:

```
clean_description = (data['other_details']['experience_detail']['description'])
**TypeError**: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Attempt 2:

```
def index():
    data = json.loads(request.data)
    clean_description = (data['other_details']['experience_detail'])
```

Output:

```
[
   {
      "description":"Location: Australia\nCurrent job responsibilities:\n\n• To manage, interpret, and integrate inspection and function test data associated with pressure relief devices\n• Collection and Managing the database of inspection/test records\n• Pressure Relief Device (PRD) Inspection Report review/approval and recommendation\n• Compliance check on inspection reports in accordance with the scope and approve and/or send for re-review\n• Database management using Meridium, SAP and other Document Control Databases",
      "employer_name":"Wood Group",
      "end_date":"2020-04-28",
      "id":"30dbe99d0c55435ea3d5119ece0ac873",
      "is_current_employer":true,
      "job_title":"Integrity Engineer",
      "start_date":"2013-11-25"
   },
   {
      "description":"Location: Australia\n\nResponsibilities:\n• Experience in pressure relief device sizing and selection\n• Exposure to Upstream Facilities Engineering activities\n• Experience with SharePoint for document management\n• Experience with Meridium",
      "employer_name":"Jacobs Engineering",
      "end_date":"2013-10-25",
      "id":"7d8afe3cadaa4aee842bb4d8b000f5c7",
      "is_current_employer":false,
      "job_title":"Integrity Engineer",
      "start_date":"2011-11-25"
   }
]
```

It is displaying all the fields but I just need the description field.

Image of payload:
[image]

Comment: You say you want the `description` field but there are multiple `description` fields. That will give you a `list` of the descriptions. The `TypeError` mentions that the object you're trying to access is of type `list`. Which is why you have to access it like `list[0]`, etc.. rather than `list['description']`.

Comment: `[i['description'] for i in data['other_details']['experience_detail']]` is a `list` comprehension that should work.

Comment: Hi @Axe319, thx for the reply, Here description field is nothing but a experience summary of candidate, for eg the request payload contains 2 description field means the person works on two organization's what exactly I am trying to do is I want to take desptn field and sanitize the content(prevents any script injections in html) this is my code clean_fielf = [field['description'] for field in data['other_details']['experience_detail']]cleaner = clean.Cleaner()sanitized_html =cleaner.clean_html(clean_description)) It is giving an error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iter'

Comment: I am sanitizing the description field using library from lxml.html import clean

Comment: From your first attempt you would have to change `data['other_details'] 
                             ['experience_detail']['description']` to `data['other_details'] 
                             ['experience_detail'][0]['description']` or swap out 0 with whichever dictionary you're trying to read. As Axe said there are multiple dictionaries with description fields inside the `experience_detail` list

Comment: Thanks @RolvApneseth for your reply, I need all the description field

Comment: Have you tried the comprehension that Axe wrote above?

Comment: yeah I tried Its working , after that I used sanitizing technique clean_description= [field['description'] for field in data['other_details']['experience_detail']]cleaner = clean.Cleaner()sanitized_html =cleaner.clean_html(clean_description)) using library from lxml.html import clean.In this sceneriao I am facing an error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iter'